# 2012 Moderator Election: Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I will be working with candidates to arrange a proper time.

***The Town Hall Chat took place on Wednesday the 19th at 10:00:00Z UTC. A digest of it can be found [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/2012-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)***

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 17th-19th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=mathematica.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: @Brett Waiting on ideally one more response. We're currently looking at Wednesday morning (UTC).

Comment: @Brett The post is what was wrong, not the register and time zone links.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I fixed the rest of the post for you. :-)

Comment: [Wolfram Time](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Wednesday+19+September+at+10%3A00+in+the+morning+UTC) - sadly I can't attend, but I hope the candidates are well grilled, if not barbecued.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Brett - guess I'm still not as awake as I should be. And thanks for the Wolfram time, cormullion

Comment: I won't be able to make it live, as it'll be 3AM here... will reply to the questions when I wake up.

Comment: What's that "Z" at the end of the time?

Comment: @celtschk I never really looked at its meaning but essentially it's used on UTC timestamps to indicate that they are UTC and thus note both the time zone and the fact that it's a 24-hour scale. Saying "UTC" afterwards as I do in these announcements is technically redundant, but not everyone knows that the Z indicates UTC.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first StackExchange election I've witnessed, but it occurs to me that there's a gap between the "comment on nominations, "ask candidates in a chat", and "vote for your three favourites" 'events' in the election process.

Wouldn't it make more sense to move the chat to a question on meta, and then allow each 'answer' to be a question from a user, and the comments to be replies. Well, it's not ideal, obviously, but there seems to be no other way for people to ask a question of each potential mod and get an answer in a timezone that suits both, without the apparent chaos of a chat transcript.

Sorry if this isn't an 'answer' to the 'question'...

Comment: [Something like this was done in math.SE...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254)

Comment: You can always ask the candidates in chat and perhaps host a meta question as J.M. notes. The Town Hall is just a more readily organized session that we always run - it's not our intention to make it the *only* time to get the juicy details from your candidates, merely making it *a* time to get juicy details. As for the chat detail - a digest will be made that will be a lot easier to read than the chat transcript, once all the candidates have answered the current set.